# Tomcat 8 + Spring @EnableAsync = app deployment error

Tags: spring, asynchronous, tomcat8

I'm a mobile developer trying to develop a server side app ;-(. It is going well but now, I am facing an annoying problem, trying to run a method in asynchronous way using Spring multitasking. Basically the method is sending an email. I was reading a little about `@Async` spring annotation and tried to use it in my implementation. 
In order to do this I had created this class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsynchConfiguration 
{
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() 
    {
         ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
         executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
         executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
         executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
         executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
         executor.initialize();
         return executor;
    }
 }
```

And then in my email service I added a new method:

```
@Async("asyncExecutor")
public void lostPetSeeAddressAsync(String nameComplete, String to, String petName, String ip, String address, String lat, String lon) throws MessagingException {
    lostPetSeeAddress(nameComplete, to, petName, ip, address, lat, lon);
}
```

Which is just calling my previous synchro method to send emails (lostPetSeeAddress).
But after this code Tomcat is failing to deploy the app. If I remove the `AsynchConfiguration` class it works well. I tried to set the Async on my xml config but it is failing in the same way. The annoying part of this is the lack of error messages in Tomcat's console. 
Perhaps somebody can help me with what I need to do or at least with some hint about how to debug or where to get logs about where and why is Tomcat failing.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the error trace on Eclipse console, when deploy fail:

INFO: Server startup in 33305 ms
Jan 30, 2020 9:37:46 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractNioInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(AbstractNioInputBuffer.java:345)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1065)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: If you change the ```PoolSize``` or the ```Queue``` to a low number, will it not run?
The code does not seem to have a problem.

Comment: Show the error you have on startup.

Comment: I edited my question to add the error trace. Thanks M. Deinum.

Comment: Being I get no answer and there is no way to know why Async configuration avoid app deployment, perhaps somebody knows how to call from spring controller a method in an asynchronous way not using @Asynch. Of course I know using a Thread works, but use it is not a good idea inside a servlet environment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an error message and could solve the problem. It was caused by a cyclic dependency on com.lowagie library for itext. Here the error message:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to complete the scan for annotations for web application [/app] due to a StackOverflowError. Possible root causes include a too low setting for -Xss and illegal cyclic inheritance dependencies. The class hierarchy being processed was [org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodableVector->org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector]

After solving the com.lowagie library problem, Spring Async configuration works fine. 
This is not a real solution but a hint for other people. Because to be honest I still having no idea about why, adding Async Spring configuration rise com.lowagie cyclic dependency problem. Perhaps Async on Spring is using org.bouncycastle? Weird, but perhaps other Spring wise people can enlighten us.